# Display child and grandchild record in reated list below parent record on single page

Tags: related-list

We have three object Opportunity ---> Vendor ---> Vendor Items. The relationship between all these objects are Master Detail. i.e. Opportunity is Master and Vendor is Detail, and Vendor is Master and Vendor Items are details.

We have a requirement to display like below on a single page

Opportunity
---> Vendor
----------- here show all vendors
---> Vendor Items
-----------here show all vendor items

While it is easy to show Vendor as related list below Opportunity. But how can I also show Vendor Items below this? Please advise. If it is LWC... please elaborate it a bit for me. thanks

Comment: this has to be done with either LWC, Aura, or VF that uses a controller to create the three-level hierarchy and the client-side renders the tree.  [REST tree resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm) could be quite useful. See also [this LWC tree example](https://www.forcetrails.com/2021/06/lazy-loading-in-lightning-tree-grid-lwc.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a lookup field on Vendor Items to Opportunity.

With a direct relationship established, you can add a related list on Opportunity.

After that, you just need to propagate the Opportunity Id from your Vendor record down to its related Vendor Item records. That would be handled by a trigger (or perhaps a record-triggered flow?).

Comment: thanks for the response. This option we dicussed but then discarded as it would further complicate the relatioships between these objects. Also, even if we do this...it wont be displayed on the same page. Pls correct if m missing anything here....

Comment: @user105281 There's no way to avoid adding complexity when you add new things. The complexity will appear _somewhere_. Adding a single new relationship field is about as little extra complexity as you'll find, in my opinion. The extra related list will also be available on the Opportunity record detail page (same as with the Vendor related list).